# Should I separate XPath's from scraping code?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I am working on a scraping project using scrapy framework, and I need to separate the `response.xpath('....')`. Is there any solution for decoupling of code and configuration or data resources: the XPaths you use can be put in a configuration file separately from the code, which would allows for easier future modifications as the xpaths are forever changing whenever the website or web app is updated.

```
def parse(self, response):
    nav_xp = "//div[@id='mainNav']//li/a/@href"
    #res = response.xpath(nav_xp).extract()
    #req = [Request(self.start_urls[0]+url) for url in res[1:-1]]
    return (Request(self.start_urls[0] + url, callback=self.parse_articles, headers=response.headers) for  url in response.xpath(nav_xp).extract()[1:-1])


def parse_articles(self, response):
    for article_section in response.xpath('//h2[@class="section_title"]/a'):
        title = article_section.xpath('text()').extract_first()
        href = article_section.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        href_splitted = article_section.xpath('@href').extract_first().split('/')[1:]
        category = href_splitted[0]
        article_id = int(''.join([char for char in href_splitted[1] if char.isdigit()]))
        article = Article()
        article['title'] = title
        article['category'] = category
        article['article_id'] = article_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to the `xpath()` function is a string, so of course you can factor those strings out of the code to a configuration file.

This is only worth doing, however, when the code is stable and the XPath's vary independent of the code.

Most scraping scripts are light-weight tools that themselves have to evolve over time.  Where something like a testing harness might have stable code and varying XPaths to express tests, generally scraping code coevolves with its XPaths such that separating the two would gain little.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
should I make a simple python file to store the those strings or there's a special config file designated for this job?

Comment: Thanks you for ur answer :)